# honda accord 1997 2.2L timing belt

Tags: timing-belt, timing

I took off the timing belt and balancing belt before finding top dead center what can I do to get everything lined up before I put belt back on

Answer (score 3):

All the important pulleys (the crank, the camshaft(s) and anything else that is vital) will have alignment marks that you can use to align them - usually an indent on the pulley and a matching mark on the end of the block/head.

Key things to remember:

- The parts are all designed to rotate together, so ideally you need to turn them all at the same time. As this probably isn't possible without the belt, you'll need to turn each of them a little bit, then the next in turn until they all line up. If you tried to line them up one at a time you could hit the pistons with the valves... This would be very tedious, so...
- Can you temporarily refit the old belt and use that to roughly line it all up? Or have the parts already turned independently of each other?
- The crankshaft turns twice as fast as the cam. It shouldn't make any difference, but you might need to turn it by more than a full turn to get the top-end lined up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to determine if the engine is interference or not.  If it is, rotating the cam(s) and crank independent of each other will destroy the engine.

Not interference - rotate away until everything lines up.

Interference - remove the cam(s), align the crank, reinstall cam(s) at proper alignment.  Since the belt is already off, removing the cam(s) should just be removing the valve cover(s) and a couple cam caps.